# Parsing through SVG Paths on page load

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, svg

EDIT:: I'm a doof. Accidentally clicked the 'prevent this page from creating more alerts' or however it reads. Swicthing to console.log() reveals that inside the scope of my $('path').each( my calls to  $(this).attr('name'); produce an undefined variable, however when we enter the scope of the .click that call to $(this).attr('name'); produces expected values.

I'm trying to finish a script that will handle classes for SVG paths. I want to add classes to the paths on page load, then modify them with clicks. The onclick works fine, but I'm a complete noob to proper jQuery structures and my searches have turned up nothing. Here's the code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
             * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
             */
                $('img.svg').each(function(){
                    var $img = $(this);
                    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
                    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
                    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

                    $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                        var $svg = $(data).find('svg');

                        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                        }


                         // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                          //detect whether the county is unlocked or not
                          imgClass = imgClass +' replaced-svg';
                        }

                        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                        // Replace image with new SVG
                        $img.replaceWith($svg);

                        // Add an handler
                        $('path').each(function() {
                          $(function() {
                            console.log('pleasegawdwork');
                            $(this).load(function(){
                              $.ajax({ url: 'scripts/get_unlocked_counties.php',
                                data: {county: $(this).attr('id')},
                                type: 'post',
                                dataType: 'text',
                                success: function(output) {
                                  if(output.unlocked == 1){
                                    //if it is add the county_unlocked class
                                    console.log('success');
                                    imgClass = imgClass +' county_unlocked replaced-svg';
                                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass);
                                  }else{
                                    //else just give it the class it already had
                                    console.log('fail');
                                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass);
                                  }
                                },
                                error: function(output){
                                  console.log(output);
                                }
                              });
                            });
                          });
                          //when you click a county
                          $(this).click(function() {
                            var name =$(this).attr('name');
                            $('.county_selected.county_unlocked').attr('class', 'county_unlocked');
                            $('.county_selected').attr('class', '');
                            if($(this).attr('class') == 'county_unlocked'){
                               $(this).attr('class', 'county_selected county_unlocked');
                            }else{
                              $(this).attr('class', 'county_selected'); 
                            }

                            //Rewrite the quick facts div via an ajax call
                            $.ajax({ url: 'scripts/map_controller.php',
                                   data: {county: name},
                                   type: 'post',
                                   dataType: 'json',
                                   success: function(output) {
                                      //rewrite any county_name divs with the clicked county's name
                                      $(".county_name").html(output.name);
                                      //add the facts list to the quick facts section
                                      $(".population").html(output.population);
                                      $(".county_seat").html(output.county_seat);
                                      $(".commodities").html(output.commodities);
                                      $(".parks_sites").html(output.parks_sites);
                                      $(".fun_facts").html(output.fun_facts);
                                      $(".not_unlocked").html('');
                                      $(".unlock_button").attr('style', 'display:none');
                                      if(output.population == '?'){
                                        $(".not_unlocked").html(output.name+' County is waiting to be unlocked!');
                                        $(".unlock_button").attr('style', 'display:visible');
                                      }
                                    },
                                    error: function(output){
                                      console.log(output);
                                    }
                            });
                          });
                       });
                    });

                });
        });
</script>
```

This code takes the SVG image and parses it into paths, then allows me to change items on the page with a .click. That part works great, ajax and all. Everything after the alert('pleasegawdwork') is what I am having trouble with; I've tried moving it, using older jQuery calls, throwing it in with and without the .load(), I can't figure it out. The ajax is sound I think, it basically returns true or false. I'm mostly confused as to why none of the alerts are working, even though the function right above it works fine. Any insight and education would be greatly appreciated. so, to sum it up:

Why aren't alerts working from alert('pleasegawdwork') onwards, and more so why does it seem that I can't get this code to run at all no matter how I move it?

Comment: Are you sure that the ajax success function is being called?  Is it possible that there is an error and the error function is being invoked instead?

Comment: That's the thing; the whole block of code from the alert down seems to not be called at all. I thought I might need to call the function through a particular handler in order for it to work side by side with the .click, but I've had no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to jQuery's `.load()` is supposed to be a URL, but you are passing a function.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a sc ope issue, and then a formatting issue. Quick tips to remember: Make sure that if your datatype is json that you are responding with properly formatted json.